# java.io.IOException: Reason for inactivity is mandatory when insert data on salesforce

Tags: java, salesforce, talend

I am using Talend for an integration with salesforce. After some stuffs I want to insert records inside salesforce:

My job is this:

[image: job]

my job works like this:

- `tSaleforceConnection` set the connection:
- `tSalesforceInput` retrieve one row of a given table
- `tMap` is mapping values to create a new record to simulate an insert inside the table
- `tSalesforceOutput` make the insert query,***in particular in this component i'm getting this error***:

> Exception in component tSalesforceOutput_1 (SalesForceConnection)
>       java.io.IOException: Reason for inactivity is mandatory

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

My `tSalesforceOutput` component:

[image: component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "Inactivity" the target object?
In this case, it seems the field "Reason" is mandatory for this object (or a validation rule checking the field is not null).
Else, can you give a little more information?

TRF

Comment: The table is Contact and inside this table there isn't a field called `Reason`

Comment: Can you share your tMap and tSalesforceOutput components?

Comment: Can you also share your tSalesforceConnection component settings?

Comment: Simply, modifying the security settings of the attributes of my table

Comment: Then the accepted answer is not the correct one. It should be modified with the solution I guess..